# postfix/lmtp User doesn't exist

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am trying to setup a postfix server with dovecot as the mail delivery agent.

When trying to send an email to bruno@2c2axxx.online-server.cloud the mail is rejected with the following error:

> Aug 14 08:19:48 localhost postfix/lmtp[563843]: 9068F7802976: to=bruno@2c2axxx.online-server.cloud, relay=2c2axxx.online-server.cloud[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.25, delays=0.19/0.01/0.02/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host 2c2axxx.online-server.cloud[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 bruno@2c2axxx.online-server.cloud **User doesn't exist**: bruno@2c2axxx.online-server.cloud (in reply to RCPT TO command))

postconf:
https://pastebin.com/qh9vkBgJ

postconf -n
https://pastebin.com/2FTq3V7k

doveconf -n:
https://pastebin.com/dFV6hB8G

What am I doing wrong?